# How to remove Below Highlighted Box

Tags: bigbluebutton

```
I have self managed BBB(2.7) with greenlight(v3) server.

I have changed text to null for in box by changing bigbluebutton configuration? 

But I want to Remove that highlighted box.
[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkKxf.png)
```

I tried to find that element(by browser element section) and search in both code repo(bbb and greenlight-v3) but not able to found where its from?